# How to provide localized resources for a nuget package?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization

I'm looking for a way to allow consumers of a NuGet package to provide their own localization for a string returned to an HTTP API caller (through ASP.NET Core middleware). The class is called `ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler` and I'm using an `IStringLocalizer<ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler>`.

On the client app (that consumes the package), I've tried to have:

- Resources\ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler.resx
- Resources\NugetPackageNamespace.ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler.resx
- Resources\Nuget\Package\Namespace\ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler.resx

Also included the `.es.resx` variants to see if different languages are picked up (client app configured [as documentation states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization)), but, those are all ignored.

If I add a Resources\ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler.resx file to the NuGet package project itself, then I get that string but not the ones specified in the client app.

How can I achieve this so that the client is the one that creates the resources, as this is a public package and I do not want to force any values/languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when you request an `IStringLocalizer` from DI, the type's assembly is what is used to get the resources.

This can be achieved by going a step lower and using an `IStringLocalizerFactory`:

```cs
var assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()!;
var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(assembly.FullName!);
var localizer = _stringLocalizerFactory.Create(nameof(ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler), assemblyName.Name!);
```

The second parameter, even though it's called `location`, asks for the name of the assembly that contains the .resx files - which in this case is the entry assembly.

In the client app, resources can be just added to the main Resources folder (Resources\ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler.resx)